How to get all groups to the Group claim in Azure B2C
In Reference to the question :- Previously asked Question, As shown in the Github.
When we call to the Graph api , using the <TechnicalProfile>, usually there can be N number of groups that user is part of.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userobjectId/transitiveMemberOf?$select=id Output is something like
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryObjects(id)",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.group",
            "id": "e23fb285-6044-4216-b8c3-45f1b9a19315"
        } ]
}

Where the Vale[] can have N Number of group. As referenced in the GitHub above, we need to declare N number of variables to hold each of them then put it in to the String Collection. How to handle it in better way.
e.g., for 3rd group
<ClaimsTransformation Id="AddGroup_3" TransformationMethod="AddItemToStringCollection">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="group_3" TransformationClaimType="item" />
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="groups" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
        </InputClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="groups" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>

I want all Id of group to be in the groups Claim of the token. By any way is fine  i.e., By any  TransformationClaimType . Out put something like in the token claim
Groups:[grp1_id,grp1_id]
How to add Group claim in the B2C user token?

To efficiently add all group IDs to the "groups" claim in the B2C user token, utilize a single ClaimsTransformation loop mechanism instead of declaring separate transformations for each group. This ensures scalability and maintainability of your policy configuration.

Are there any ClaimsTransformation methods to loop?
